# Android API authorization header values

Tags: android, json

In order to practice and learn about Android I am doing a simple meteorologic App, for this I am using an api that sent to the device the local weather. I have to sent to this API my location by Json and two headers values , I have this example in the api documentation:

> HTTP method PUT
>   Authorization header values:
>   deviceid=8489456AZXXXXXX, api_key=354337637ARA3453463ZRXXXXXXX,
>   basicauthentication
>
> Request Data example:                                                                    { latitude:123456789, longitude:123456789}

So my problem basicly is that I don´t know who to use the header values and I can not connect with the api, I am trying this below code but I am getting this error:

> "InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException", "message":"The given id must not
>   be null!"

```
public JSONObject callApi (String url) {

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(url);
        httpPut.addHeader("deviceid","8489456AZXXXXXX");
        httpPut.addHeader("api_key","354337637ARA3453463ZRXXXXXXX");

        String json = "";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        jsonObject.accumulate("latitude",123122312);
        jsonObject.accumulate("longitude",1231321123);


        json = jsonObject.toString();
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
        httpPut.setEntity(se);


        httpPut.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPut.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        if (inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }


    try {
        jsonSent = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jsonSent;

}
```

What I am doing wrong?. 
Thanks

Comment: Who knows how this API works, only you can tell what is wrong. Since you did not link to the documentation at least

Comment: thanks @meda is all documentation I have

Comment: Ok well without knowing how the API works, no one can guess the issue, thats why you are not getting answers

Comment: @meda one more time thanks, I have news from the API support, the translation more or less says:
"You have to add the api key and device id to the authorization header also basic authentication is required to get your local weather"